# How to compare two json array with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example I have this dataInput json:

```
dataInput= [
    {text: 'text1'},
    {text: 'text2'},
    {text: 'text3'}
];
```

and I want to compare it with:

```
dataInputUpdated= [
  {text: 'text1', info: 'something'},
  {text: 'text2'},
  {text: 'text3'}
];
```

How to compare between them with Typescript? Is there any equal method? This is array of objects, so I wanna know its not equal on any change.

Comment: Is the order of the objects in the array always going to be the same?

Comment: Yes, the order is the same. The change will be something inside each object, for example change in value of property or added proprety

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify` method to do the comparison. Here is a sample:

```
let dataInput= [
    {text: 'text1'},
    {text: 'text2'},
    {text: 'text3'}
];

let dataInputUpdated= [
  {text: 'text1', info: 'something'},
  {text: 'text2'},
  {text: 'text3'}
];

let areSame: boolean = JSON.stringify(dataInput) === JSON.stringify(dataInputUpdated);

alert(areSame); // returns false
```

Comment: Would this return true if `info` wasn't there AND `dataInput` had text2 first and text1 second, where `dataInputUpdated` had text1 first and text2 second?

Comment: Its text comparison so for the result to be true, they need to be in same order.